# Looking for a dictionary based .NET text compression library

Tags: .net, compression

I am looking for a .NET dictionary based compression library, something that would allow me 'seed' it with a large list / string of common words which it would use to build its dictionary.

The reason that I want this over LZMA and the like is because I want to independently compress short strings, all of which are quite similar to each other. Visualize compressing a simple children's book, but compressing each page separately. If we were compressing the whole book then LZMA would be good, but it's not so great for shorter strings.

Does any such thing exist?

Comment: It almost seems like you are asking for something that will inject arbitrary, unnecessary data in order to get a higher compression percentage. Sort of like buying 100 of something to save 10%, when you really only need the 1. Or, I'm misunderstanding something. Which is quite possible, too.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I would have thought that most compression algorithms would already take care of this. They operate at the bit level and are very effective. If you think you can do it better, try writing your own.

Comment: @LachlanB I *think* what he's getting at is the idea that you get a better compression *ratio* with larger, repeating sets of data. For example, if you have the word "purple" repeated a thousand times in a piece of text of modest size, it will compress better than if you only have that word once. Same reason a solid, single-colored PNG file is about the same file size regardless of it's physical size. But he seems to want to *Add* extra data just to achieve extra compression ratio.

Comment: Would the desired output be self contained, i.e. contain the dictionary or the applicable subset thereof, or would a separate reference dictionary be needed to decompress the various "pages"?

Comment: My apologies - I forgot to include that important aspect that  user92546 guessed. Yes -- I would have a single reference dictionary available that would be required to decompress a page.

Answer (score 2):

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) provides dictionary based compression.  The functions deflateSetDictionary() and inflateSetDictionary() do exactly what you describe.

Comment: OK, thanks. I just need to .NETify it now.

Comment: @Mr. Flibble: That has already been done; see the directory contrib/dotzlib in the ZLib package.

Comment: dotzlib unfortunately does not provide an interface to the *SetDictionary functions.  Though perhaps that could be used as a starting point for Mr. Flibble.  (Mr. Flibble.  Mr. Flibble.  I like saying that.  Mr. Flibble.)

Comment: Then maybe Mr. Flibble could submit an updated version of dotzlib.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in GZip: [GZipStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx). You should deploy it as a SQLCLR UDF function for your needs, see [How to: Create and Run a SQL Server User-Defined Function by using Common Language Run-time Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx)

Comment: I don't see anything in that class that supports setting dictionaries.  Unless there is an interface that provides that, this user will need to use the zlib library directly.